# I'm trying to identify this herb

Tags: leaves, herbs, mint

[image]I've tried other websites and there's no exact lookalike plant. There're countless plants that look similar but I've never seen leaves that look exactly the same. The stem is fuzzy and square like the mint family and the leaves are also slightly fuzzy. I keep hearing sage but they are green, nowhere near as long and not jagged. There're 2 sets of leaves that grow across from each other all the way up. When crushing a leaf with my fingers it smells slightly minty fresh but also sweet. I have basil and spearmint and am sure it's neither of those. The smaller leaves don't smell minty at all while the larger leaves smell minty on a half pressured squeeze then when I squeeze harder they smell only sweet (to me). There're about 30 plant stems growing very closely together but definitely not from the same stem.

Comment: It is difficult to find out what species it is. You already did a good job on narrowing down the family. But such family is large, so it is difficult to distinguish it from just one photo. You may add more photos, or just wait for the flowers. Some additional information: where do you live (climate zone/continent)? Is it a wild plant, or from a garden?